# How to set the default app that will run an executable file

Tags: node.js, bash, assembly, executable

I'm working on an assembler that gets assembly code and generates machine code in a binary file.

On the other side I develop an interpreter that reads the machine code generated and interprets it.

I do something like this:

```
myas foo.asm -o out
myint out
```

(`myas` is my assembler application and `myint` is the interpreter application and both are *nodejs* applications)

Is there a way to set the program that runs the executable file in the executable file, somehow?

Instead doing `myint out` I want to do `./out` (running it as executable).

If I have an executable file that I want to run with `node` I put this on the first line: `#!env/node`.

How can I set `myint` command to run `out` file?

Comment: Can you use a shell script and call this script from node?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin I don't get what you mean. Right now `myint` is a NodeJS app (command line tool) that reads the binary file and gives some output, interpreting it.

Comment: Oh, I see, your question is a bit unclear in this part :)

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin You may edit it to make it clear. :-)

Comment: @Ionica that's what I did :)

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin Thanks. Actually the question can be language agnostic, supposing I have a buffer built from `0` and `1` in the binary file, how can I set the executable runner?

Comment: You can always have the first line of `out` to have an appropriate shebang: `#!/path/to/myint`. Then modify your interpreter so that it skips the first line of a file if it start by `#!`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Yes, I already thought at the solution, but is it the correct way? I guess it's more or less a workaround only...

Comment: If your file is not an ELF or if it doesn't have a shebang, it won't execute. So you have very few options here.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf that's not true on linux, where you have the [binfmt_misc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc) magic available.

Comment: @Jester Can you add an answer how to use it?

Comment: There are two examples on the linked wikipedia page. binfmt configuration might not be on-topic for SO.

Comment: @Jester I guess it's fine to post here the answer since a question that will help other people probably. I would like how can I do this with NodeJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied the *hack* with the `env` start.

The assembler knows to append first the snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env arc-int
```

I also make the file executable:

```
Fs.chmodSync(OUTPUT_FILE, 0755);
```

And then the interpreter knows to not to interpret that snippet.

I [open-sourced the assembler and the interpreter here](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/arc-assembler).